# Getting days from previous date in transactional data using Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataset of transactional data, where many transactions can incur every day but not all days will have transactions. I want to calculate for each transaction the number of days since the closest day in past (excluding the current day) with a transaction.

```
from StringIO import StringIO

import pandas as pd

TESTDATA=StringIO("""time,message
2015-02-01,x
2015-02-01,z
2015-02-02,x
2015-02-04,y
2015-02-04,z
""")

s = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=",",parse_dates=[0])
```

What I want is:

```
2015-02-01,x,nan
2015-02-01,z,nan
2015-02-02,x,1
2015-02-04,y,2
2015-02-04,z,2
```

Comment: I can't test this but I think you can use pd.merge_asof. Maybe someone else can mess with that and give an answer

Comment: @piRSquared correct :)

Answer (score 2):

With merge_asof:

```
s['time2'] = s['time']
df = pd.merge_asof(s, s, left_on='time', right_on='time', allow_exact_matches=False)
df
Out[328]: 
        time message_x    time2_x message_y    time2_y
0 2015-02-01         x 2015-02-01       NaN        NaT
1 2015-02-01         z 2015-02-01       NaN        NaT
2 2015-02-02         x 2015-02-02         z 2015-02-01
3 2015-02-04         y 2015-02-04         x 2015-02-02
4 2015-02-04         z 2015-02-04         x 2015-02-02

df.time - df.time2_y
Out[330]: 
0      NaT
1      NaT
2   1 days
3   2 days
4   2 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was imagining. Answering questions on my phone is the worst.

Comment: @piRSquared  I abandonned that, just read-only, upvote, comments, typos.